# How Only get name easyImage Android?

Tags: java, android, easyimage

**Before**

[/data/user/0/com.example.hx_loom.evpa/cache/EasyImage/a85f8011-10d5-4050-89d2-1e575da55522.jpg,

/data/user/0/com.example.hx_loom.evpa/cache/EasyImage/4737a29f-7df2-4e1f-abe3-18b71293d76e.jpg]

**After**
a85f8011-10d5-4050-89d2-1e575da55522.jpg,4737a29f-7df2-4e1f-abe3-18b71293d76e.jpg

please help me this algoritma

Comment: so you want to get file name from path?

Comment: yes,I want save to Sql

Comment: have you searched before asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get file name from file path in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570084/how-to-get-file-name-from-file-path-in-android)

Comment: yes it works, but only for 1 file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern of the directory of your images is always the same you can incorporate a regular expression to parse everything after EasyImage/.

You can [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478190/regex-combine-a-match-for-everything-after-the-last-slash-and-exclude-the-last-c):

```
([^\/]+)(?=$)
```

It matches any character after the last slash.

Comment: how multiple image array?

Comment: Iham Solehudin - I don't understand what you are asking. If you want this to work on an array then apply the regex for each element in the array.